# SSIS: How to truncate tables data before insert

Tags: sql-server

I have created a package which is inserting records into 3 tables (Separate flow for each) and it is working fine. Now I want to truncate data from these 3 tables before insert.
I have written stored procedure to truncate data from these 3 tables but not succeeded.
It is working fine for a single table.

Comment: Could you post the text of the stored proc?

Answer (score 2):

Use an Execute SQL Task on the control flow, and add this task before insert table operation takes place. Add the following code in the Execute SQl task

```
  Truncate Table <Tbl_1>
  Truncate Table <Tbl_2>
  Truncate Table <Tbl_3>
```

Comment: If you are using Execute SQL Task for Inserts then you can include Truncate table statement before Insert operation takes place.

Comment: Also are you getting any error while you are trying to truncate the table.

Comment: If I write TRUNCATE statements into SQL Statements field then it works fine, but I want to write all truncate stmts into stored procedure instead of writing all in the SQL Staements field, and use that stored procedure name into SQL Staement field.

Comment: You need to put the SQL Task (Truncate commands or SP) before the start of the three insert control flows.  If you are doing it as part of the individual control flows, and the SP clears all tables, then you will get some unexpected results. Otherwise, there should be some kind of error message to help explain the missing truncate.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your delete statements in an "Execute SQL Task" by separating them with an `;`. and you put the task before your flow :

[image]

[image]